# Count different symbols in a string in c

Tags: c

A user has to insert a string and in that string I have to count the different symbols. For example: "Ellipse" has got 6 different symbols while the whole word has 7 symbols, the different symbols are: "E,l,i,p,s,e".

I was able to write a code that counts the symbols correctly, but I have really big problems with writing those symbols!
Please note: I am NOT allowed to use any other libraries (for example string.h).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 256

        int main()
    {

        int VOwels=0,diff=0,counter,i,j;
        char vowels[]={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};

        char sentence[MAX], diff_symbols[MAX];

        printf("\nInsert sentence: ");
        gets(sentence);

        for(i=0;sentence[i]!='\0';i++){
            if(i==0){
                diff_symbols[i]=sentence[i];//first symbols is always saved
                diff++;
            }
            counter=0;//Reset counter
            if(i!=0){
                for(j=0;diff_symbols[j]!='\0';j++){//checking if the symbol was already observed
                    if(sentence[i]==diff_symbols[j]){
                        counter++;
                        break;//as soon as we find the same symbol we stop checking
                        }
                }
                if(counter==0){//if we haven't found that symbol in the diff_symbols yet than
                    diff_symbols[j]=sentence[i];
                    diff++;
                    }
            }
            for(j=0;vowels[j]!='\0';j++){//counting vowels
                if(sentence[i]==vowels[j]){
                    VOwels++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Inserted sentence is: %s",sentence);
        printf("\nThere are %d symbols in the string\n",i);
        printf("There are %d different symbols in the string. The symbols are: %s\n",diff,diff_symbols);
        printf("Number of vowels %d.\n",VOwels);
        return 0;
    }
```

The result is almost good. The numbers match, except when I am trying to write all the different symbols something really strange happens - some strange symbols that should not be there.

Any ideas? :/

Comment: since when `string.h` became a library?

Comment: `gets()` is pure evil. use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: `for(j=0;diff_symbols[j]!='\0';j++`. You have not initialised `diff_symbols`. So that is Undefined Behaviour as you are accessing elements in that array that have not been set.

Comment: what is the error code exactly? what is the strange "thing"? please post what results you are getting, and what are the expected results!

Comment: Do the symbols have to be in order they appear in the string? For example, if the input string is `"tatter"`, should the output be `taer` or is `aert` fine?

Comment: Related to `diff_symbols` being uninitialised, you cannot use `%s` to print it as that requires a NUL terminated string (which you are not guaranteed to have). Try initialising it at the top first: `char diff_symbols[MAX] = { 0 };`

Comment: Thanks to kaylum and blazs for the answer! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `diff_symbols` is not initialized. The program works fine if you set `char diff_symbols[256]={0}`.

A much simpler algorithm would be to iterate through the string and turn on the cell of `diff_symbols` if the corresponding character appears in the string. Then walk over the array and print the character iff the corresponding cell is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 256

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiouAEU";
    char diff_symbols[MAX] = { '\0' };
    char sentence[MAX]; 

    size_t total_cnt, diff_cnt, vowels_cnt;
    size_t i;

    printf( "\nInsert sentence: " );
    fgets( sentence, MAX, stdin );

    total_cnt = diff_cnt = vowels_cnt = 0;

    for ( i = 0; sentence[i] != '\n' && sentence[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        diff_symbols[( unsigned char )sentence[i]] = 1;
        size_t j = 0;
        while ( vowels[j] != '\0' && vowels[j] != sentence[i] ) ++j;
        vowels_cnt += vowels[j] != '\0';
    }

    if ( sentence[i] == '\n' ) sentence[i] = '\0';

    total_cnt = i;

    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++ ) diff_cnt += diff_symbols[i];

    printf( "\nInserted sentence is: %s\n", sentence );
    printf( "There are %zu symbols in the string\n", total_cnt );
    printf( "There are %zu different symbols in the string.", diff_cnt ); 
    printf( "The symbols are: " );
    for ( i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++ ) 
    {
        unsigned char c = sentence[i];
        if ( diff_symbols[c] ) 
        {
            diff_symbols[c] = 0;
            putchar( sentence[i] );
        }           
    }
    printf( "\n" );
    printf( "Number of vowels %zu.\n", vowels_cnt );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
Ellipse
```

then the program output will look

```
Insert sentence: Ellipse

Inserted sentence is: Ellipse
There are 7 symbols in the string
There are 6 different symbols in the string.The symbols are: Elipse
Number of vowels 3.
```

Also you could add code that would not count for example the blank character.